# R create boxplot based on columns data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with the following columns:

| id | duration1 | duration2 | duration3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 250 | 140 |
| 2 | 300 | 270 | 200 |
| 3 | 250 | 200 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 | 210 | 400 |

I want to plot the values of duration1, duration2, and duration3 in a boxplot with the column names (duration1,...2,...3) as labels of the x-axis and their column values as y-vales.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LePRr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame('id' = c(1,   500,    250,    140), 
                  'duration1' = c(2,    300,    270,    200), 
                  'duration2' = c(3,    250,    200,    300), 
                  'duration3' = c(4,    400,    210,    400), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F) 

dat_plot <- dat %>%
         pivot_longer(-id)
 
 p <- ggplot(dat_plot)+   geom_boxplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) 
 p
```

[image: required output]
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380391/creating-a-boxplot-for-two-different-column-of-data-frame-using-ggplot/64380450)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
 data1 <- tibble(
        id = 1:4,
        duration1 = c(500,300,250,400),
        duration2 = c(250,270,200,210),
        duration3 = c(140,200,300,400)
 )
  data1 <- data1 %>%
     pivot_longer(-id)

  boxpl <- ggplot(data1, aes(x=name, y=value, fill = name)) + 
     geom_boxplot() + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thats the plot. But instead of the id on the x-axis I would like to have the columns names (duration1, duration2, duration3) there and all three in one plot.

Comment: @Jonas I will correct, but you can see an answer above...