# Constructing multiple boxplots in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a movie data with respect to different genres. My ultimate objective is to create a  box plot of age wise ratings of films for different genres i.e. if action is one of the genres, I want to create a box plot of age wise ratings with each box plot representing a certain age group.
I tried using the code :

```
boxplot(cbind(Action_Subset$U_18_ratings,Action_Subset$Between_18_to_29_ratings,Action_Subset$Between_30_to_44_ratings,Action_Subset$Ratings_above_45))
```

I am able to create the box plots but unable to represent it according to different age groups.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdUlo.png)

How can I highlight which boxplot represents ratings for particular age group.

Comment: Please refer to the image description and guide me.

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687520/r-create-boxplot-based-on-columns-data/69687649#69687649

Answer (score 0):

Expecting that each column has same number of rows!

```
    data_boxplot <- cbind(Action_Subset$U_18_ratings,
                          Action_Subset$Between_18_to_29_ratings,
                          Action_Subset$Between_30_to_44_ratings,
                          Action_Subset$Ratings_above_45) %>% 
mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% 
pivot_longer(-ID)

p <- ggplot(dat_plot)+   geom_boxplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = name)) 
p
```